# Oracle APEX 5.1 Interactive Grid Cascading LOV

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

As the title suggests, I have an interactive grid in Apex5.1 which enables the users to edit existing rows. As an example there are 3 columns called

- COL_Regions (Select List),
- COL_Countries (Shuttle) and
- COL_Products (Shuttle)

Those set as Shuttles is because the user can select multiples. These 3 columns correspond to 3 tables, with countries having a foreign key to regions, and products having a foreign key to countries. Countries has been setup as having regions as parent LOV, and of course products has countries as parent LOV.

So when the user selects a region (example Europe), the countries Select List should only show European countries, and then when selecting a country, the Products Shuttle should only show products specific to that country. SQL for each Select List/Shuttle as follows:

```
select region_name, region_id from regions

select country_name, country_id from countries where region_id = :COL_REGION

select product_name, product_id from products where product_id = :COL_COUNTRIES
```

I used cascading LOVs many times in APEX forms, but somehow this is not working in interactive grids. My first question would be, should this also work in interactive grids? If yes, maybe I am referencing an interactive grid column wrong? I appreciate if you could provide an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the shuttle controls to checkbox.

Whilst shuttle parent LOV work in regular forms, they do not work in interactive grids, it must be a bug in APEX 5.1. So as a workaround, just use checkbox control.